# How do i get the point/coordinate the user clicked on an android view?

Tags: android, view, onclick

I have an imageview and when clicked, calls `OnClickListener.onClick(View v)`. How do I get the exact point/coordinate that the user clicked?

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't get the coordinate touched in OnClickListerner.
Please use OnTouchListener.onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) instead of it, 
and you could get the coordinate from the event.