# OnClick and onTouch

Tags: android, onclick

I have a activity where I have two imagesViews.

This to imagesViews has onClickListener, because I need to know which imageView was clicked. After when I click choosen picture I get result which picture was clicked.

I Know need the same result but I need to know where exacly I click on this image. I need precise coordinates where this imageView was clicked. I know that in onTouch method I have functions like I need.

**Can I change onClick method on onTouch? Or in onClick can get precise coordinates?**

Comment: You can use onTouch event ... refer this link


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122679/difference-between-ontouch-and-onclick-android

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need for you to use the `onClick` event, since you can easily capture the click using the `onTouch` callback. A click is a sequence of one `ACTION_DOWN` action, several `ACTION_MOVE` actions and one `ACTION_UP` action. These can be acquired using the `event.getAction()` method. If you get an `ACTION_DOWN` event and then an `ACTION_UP` event - it means that the user has just clicked your `View`. You can also measure time spent between these events to be sure that it was a simple click, not a long one. And, of course, you can use the `event.getX()` and `event.getY()` methods to get the exact touch point. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

you can use onTouch() method for getting touch coordinates

```
touchView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Touch coordinates : " +
            String.valueOf(event.getX()) + "x" + String.valueOf(event.getY()));
            return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

onclick cannot do this. You can get them only from an onTouchListener.

> [a question with this info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3657243/how-do-i-get-the-point-coordinate-the-user-clicked-on-an-android-view)