# How to get the position on custom view onclick

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

In custom `view` for a particular `view` on Click I am unable to get the position, please help me.

```
holder.operation.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.v("onClick", "Position: " + v.getTag());
    }
});
```

Comment: show how are you setting the tag ?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3657243/how-do-i-get-the-point-coordinate-the-user-clicked-on-an-android-view

Answer (score 1):

use this code , this will work for you.

```
holder.operation.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Object tag =v.getTag();
        if(tag!=null)
        {      
            int position = (Integer)tag;
            Log.v("onClick", "Position: " + position);
         }   

    }
});
```

you can set your position like this using tag in adaptor:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
 holder.operation.setTag(position);
}
```

Comment: Log.v("onClick", "Position: "+position);